# Reactive HTML textbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to set up my .html and .js files so that when a checkbox is ticked, some text changes.

In the header of my html, I have:

```
<!-- My own code -->
<script src="js/mycode.js"></script>
```

In the body of my html, I have:

```
<input id="TitleCheckbox2" name="TitleCheckbox2" value="your_value" type="checkbox">
    <p  id="TitleCheckText2">  Do you want to strike-out this text? </p>
```

In my code.js file, I have:

```
<script>
    if (document.getElementById('TickleCheckbox2').checked) {
        document.getElementById("TitleCheckText2").textContent="<strike>Do you want to strike-out this text?</strike>";
    } else { 
        document.getElementById("TitleCheckText2").textContent="Do you want to strike-out this text? " 
    }
</script>
```

Edit: 
The "mycode.js" file having ... tags stopped the script from working! These are superfluous, and not helpful here!

After removing these tags, and using Manish's answer, the text changes in the desired manner when the checkbox is ticked.

Comment: Tip: using `<label>` means you can also click on the text to activate the checkbox.

Comment: What @gcampbell wrote is correct. You can replace `<p  id="TitleCheckText2">` with `<label  for="TitleCheckbox2" id="TitleCheckText2">` (Note the `for` attribute referencing to the checkbox element)

Comment: @AlonEitan The alternative is to put the `<input>` inside the `<label>`.

Comment: @gcampbell Also correct, only that in the current scenario the content of `TitleCheckText2` gets overwritten when checking/unchecking the checkbox - So the OP anyway must use a new LABEL (And not replace it with the existing P element as I previously suggested)

Comment: CSS-only solution: https://jsfiddle.net/eg7j5tw2/ (with a paragraph too: https://jsfiddle.net/hqwnays9/)

Comment: That's pretty tidy, but doesn't it apply for all checkboxes?

Comment: It does, but it is CSS, so, you can change it to your liking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attached [JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/manishghec/pqqs1h4p/)

You need to user innerHTML for forming html tags.

**Javascript:**

```
 function checkboxstatus(currentObj){   
    if (currentObj.checked) {
    document.getElementById("TitleCheckText2").innerHTML="<strike>Do you want to strike-out this text?</strike>";
} else {
    document.getElementById("TitleCheckText2").innerHTML="Do you want to strike-out this text? " 
}
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="TitleCheckbox2" name="TitleCheckbox2" value="your_value" type="checkbox" onclick="checkboxstatus(this);">
    <p  id="TitleCheckText2">  Do you want to strike-out this text? </p>
```

Comment: I'm testing this code in my website (saved, for sure) in Chrome, and the text isn't reacting to the textbox - although the example you gave in JS Fiddle works as desired. Does anybody know why I'm not getting the same experience on my own site?

Comment: did you create the JS function in code.js and all it in your html file as defined in the example ?

Comment: did you call `onclick="checkboxstatus(this);"` within checkbox.

Comment: If this is the case then check if there are two ids with same name for "TitleCheckText2"

Comment: ok.. then can you please try console.log(currentObj) just after function call and see if you are getting this object or not. and just try to set some static text at the starting of function call and see if you able to find the issue or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115584/discussion-between-manish-and-idios).

Answer (score 3):

Use innerHTML rather textContent

```
document.getElementById("TitleCheckText2").innerHTML="<strike>Do you want to strike-out this text?</strike>";
```